# SP Flash Tool | Error. Status_preloader_invalid

Tags: twrp, flashtool

I am trying to write a custom recovery (TWRP) using SP_Flash_Tool but I get a Status_preloader_invalid error.
The device is "OPPO F1S" with chipset MT6755.

Here is a screenshot of the error and the scatter file I am using.
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1nyQQKPbYot_YxWwHN5lScNAEq84h-o3A

I tried to create the scatter file using Mtk_Droid_Tool but the creation button was greyed out (MT67xx is not supported) so I found a scatter file online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the scatter file. Using a correct one fixed the problem.